# Remove last comma from string using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using the Supersized jQuery plugin and need to remove the last comma from the list of images so it works in IE. 
The Supersized plugin does not work in IE if there is a comma after the last image, this is a known issue.

I am using Business Catalyst, so this is not PHP.

This is how the list of images appear, with a trailing comma:

```
{image : 'melbourne.jpg'},{image : 'tunnel.jpg'},{image : 'building.jpg'},
```

What would be the best way to do this?

```
    jQuery(function($){
            $.supersized({
                slide_interval          :   3000,       
                transition              :   1,          
                transition_speed        :   700,        

                slides                  :   [  // Slideshow Images  
                                               {module_webapps,9198,a template="/Layouts/WebApps/slide.tpl"}
                                            ]
            });
        });
```

And this is what /Layouts/WebApps/slide.tpl looks like. Basically just looping through the slider images...

```
{image : '{tag_bg image_value}'},
```

Comment: The question is not clear, what comma? What string? Why doesn't it work in IE? Are you sure that's the issue?

Comment: This seems to be a PHP question and not jQuery at all. The script that generates the images data is on the server-side not the client-side. You should include the complete PHP code that generates the data.

Answer (score 5):

You can use regulare expression on your string like that :

```
var modifiedString = yourString.replace(/,\s*$/, '');
```

This will remove the last comma IF there is one and will also remove white space.

Comment: That removes the first occurrence of a comma. Please correct into maybe `/,\s*$/`.

Comment: @kristinalim oh crap, i forogt the most important part of the regexp, thank!

Answer (score 1):

Try substring to remove last comma

```
var data = "{image : 'melbourne.jpg'},{image : 'tunnel.jpg'},{image : 'building.jpg'},";
    data = data.substr(0, data.length-1);

    console.log( data );
```

Answer (score 0):

If Business Catalyst doesn't give you the flexibility to do the Django-style `{if forloop.last},{endif}` tags, consider changing your

```
]
```

into

```
{}]
```

or

```
undefined]
```

so there won't be a trailing comma. Note that your `supersized` plugin will need to know how to process these "incorrect" values.